# how to pass values from word document as an input to the text box of the javascript and run it over a loop

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

this is a very useful tool for me which converts shivaji font to unicode

http://hindi-fonts.com/tools/shivaji-to-Unicode-Converter

my task is to convert lot of text to unicode - heres a  sample

example: shivaji font
AyaM inaja: prao vaoit gaNanaa laGaucaotsaama\ a
]darcairtanaaM tu vasauQaoOva kuTumbakma\ aa
"This person is my kin and that one is alien,” such a thought occurs only to the narrow-minded
persons. To the broad-minded persons the whole world is a family.

I paste the first two lines in the text box - it returns the unicode  - now i have a huge document - how do i do this programmatically

to be even more specific -- i want to run the javascript code embedded in the source over and over again by taking the inputs from a file - instead of feeding the text from a browser

ideas? possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
str.charCodeAt(n);
```

Will return the given char as Unicode in Javascript. Loop over the whole text and done.

Notepad++ also has a plugin that will automatically convert text to unicode, might be worth checking that out

Comment: right -- but my source is in shivaji font which the tool @ http://hindi-fonts.com/tools/shivaji-to-Unicode-Converter is good at doing -- any idea how to invoke this code